# how to add filter to MDX in the most efficient way?

Tags: mdx

How can I add in following MDX, the filter to get only results with **[Percent_Of_Clicks] >= 0.01** ?

```
with 

SET [Selected Measures] AS {[Measures].[CPC], [Measures].[CTR], [Measures].[Cost], [Measures].[Clicks]} 

member [Sum_Of_Clicks] as sum({[KW Dim].[KWs].[KW] * [Ads Dim].[Ads].[Title] * [Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country]},[Measures].[Clicks])
member [Percent_Of_Clicks] as (iif(isempty([Measures].[Clicks]) or [Measures].[Clicks] = 0,0,([Measures].[Clicks]/[Sum_Of_Clicks]))),FORMAT_STRING = "0.00"

SELECT ORDER(NONEMPTY({[KW Dim].[KWs].[KW].ALLMEMBERS * [Ads Dim].[Ads].[Title].ALLMEMBERS * [Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country].ALLMEMBERS}),ASC) ON ROWS,
{[Selected Measures], [Percent_Of_Clicks],[Sum_Of_Clicks]} ON COLUMNS

FROM [CubeName]

WHERE {[Time].[Day ID].&[20140901]:[Time].[Day ID].&[20140914]} * {[Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country].[UK]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is it exactly you want to filter (all axis? specific dimension?)
but have you tried simply wrapping up the axis with FILTER function:

> SET [Selected Measures] AS {[Measures].[CPC], [Measures].[CTR], [Measures].[Cost], [Measures][Clicks]}
>
> member [Sum_Of_Clicks] as sum({[KW Dim].[KWs].[KW] * [Ads Dim].[Ads].[Title] * [Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country]},[Measures].[Clicks])
>
> member [Percent_Of_Clicks] as (iif(isempty([Measures].[Clicks]) or [Measures].[Clicks] = 0,0,([Measures].[Clicks]/[Sum_Of_Clicks]))),FORMAT_STRING = "0.00"
>
> SELECT ORDER(
>   **FILTER(**
>       NONEMPTY({[KW Dim].[KWs].[KW].ALLMEMBERS * [Ads Dim].[Ads].[Title].ALLMEMBERS * [Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country].ALLMEMBERS})
>       **,[Percent_Of_Clicks]>=0)**
>   ,ASC
>
> ) ON ROWS,
>   {[Selected Measures], [Percent_Of_Clicks],[Sum_Of_Clicks]} ON COLUMNS
>
> FROM [CubeName]
>
> WHERE {[Time].[Day ID].&[20140901]:[Time].[Day ID].&[20140914]} * {[Country Dim].[Countrs].[Country].[UK]}